# AS3 after line breaks removing spaces and tabs before any word

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have a string like this:

> ```
> My first line\n
>    2nd line having lots of spaces/tabs and\n
>        this continues
> ```

I'm trying to remove all the spaces and tabs that starts after the line breaks and before any line character. So this would look like:

> My first line\n
>   2nd line having lots of spaces/tabs and\n
>   this continues

I have this regexp to remove the whitespaces before a character, but having difficulty to add line breaks condition in proper manner:

```
var regex:RegExp = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
var newText:String = abcd.replace(regex, "\n");
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

After some googling, I found that `^` may not fit my requirement:

> ^ - Beginning of the line

So I replaced the said character with following:

```
var regex:RegExp = /(\r?\n|\r)+(\s+|\s+$)/g;
var newText:String = abcd.replace(regex, "\n");
```

This worked properly my purpose.